# asp.net membership account valid until

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, account-management

I'm developing an application that requires user accounts to automatically be disabled if they haven't renewed their membership

Is there an easy way to do this with ASP.NET membership framework, where it is possible to define/set an expiration date?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in your case, you can use profile provider along with membership provider. Just create a profile property for expiry date, and set it when new user is registered. Update login functionality of site to check for expiry of user in that profile property.

That's the only simplest way I can see.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks, I google and google and by the looks of things, I will have to either (a) use profiles as you suggested, or (b) create a table which links to the aspnet_users table which can be used to hold more information about the user i.e. first name etc. Thanks for your help